# PostgreSQL Function: Capture exception and go next in LOOP

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to implement a function which essentially computes different aggregated values and inserts these values as a row in a new table.

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction() RETURNS void AS 
$$
DECLARE 

    table_name CHARACTER VARYING(100);
    loop_var RECORD;

    var1 INT;
    var2 INT;
    var3 INT;
  
BEGIN

    FOR loop_var IN (SELECT user FROM users) LOOP
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var1 FROM another_table WHERE user = registro.user;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var2 FROM another_table WHERE user = registro.user;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var3 FROM another_table WHERE user = registro.user;
    INSERT INTO new_table VALUES(loop_var.user,var1,var2,var3);
    END LOOP;
    
END
$$ language 'plpgsql'
;
```

**QUESTION:**

I would like to capture the exceptions when there is a problem in any of my select statements or in any of my inserts. I would like to capture the exception, skip that user (if there is any issue with it) and continue the loop.

I have tried using `EXCEPTION WHEN raise_exception THEN '% : %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;` but it did not work. Also, if I use RAISE EXCEPTION, the loop does not continue.

Could you please help me on the sintaxi I should follow in order to achieve the above goals?

Comment: Please don't "tag spam" with so many different version (3 of them not even being supported any more). Please add only one tag for the Postgres version you are really using.

Comment: Why are you running the same query three times? The value of var2 and var3 will never be different than the value for var1

Comment: Why do you use a loop? It looks like you could do it with just a single INSERT ... SELECT statement.

Comment: What kind of exceptions are you expecting? Is that the actual code or are you doing more to these counts than shown?